# How can I make in woocommerce email the product name to be a link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce eshop and I am trying to modify woocommerce emails.

More specificaly I want the product name to be a link to the product, so as the customer to be able to go back and make a review for the product.

I was thinking to put in email header something like.. "Please click on product to review it"

How can I make the product title to be a link?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'ts_email_header', 10, 2 );
function ts_email_header( $email_heading, $email ) { 
    echo '<a href="'.wp_review_url( Review_url() ).'"></a>Please click on product to review it';
}
```